# Adding a chart in Google Sheets with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I'm trying to add a chart in a sheet on Google Sheets but Google Script is saying "Cannot find method insertChart(Charts.Chart). (line 39, file "Code")".
But I'm using the method that written in the documentation. What am I doing wrong ?

```
function doGet()
{
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    //
    var artistsArray;
    var dataArtists;
    //
    artists = {};
    dataArtists = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Artists')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Count');
    //  
    for (var line = 2 ; line <= ss.getDataRange().getNumRows() ; line++)
    {
      value = sheet.getRange(line, 3).getValue();
      if (isNaN(artists[value]))
        artists[value] = 1;
      else
        artists[value]++;
    }
    //
    for(var key in artists)
    {
      console.log(key, artists[key])
      dataArtists.addRow([key, artists[key]]);
    }
    dataArtists.build()
    //
    var artistsChart = Charts.newBarChart()
      .setDataTable(dataArtists)
      .setTitle('Number of Tracks per Artist')
      .setXAxisTitle('Number of  Tracks')
      .setYAxisTitle('Artists')
      .setDimensions(600, 500)
      .build();
      //
    sheet.insertChart(artistsChart);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a [Chart object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart.html) using Charts service functions. To use [`insertChart()` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart), you need an [EmbeddedChart object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart.html) from the Spreadsheet service. To create an embedded chart use [`newChart()` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart) and to edit it use [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder.html) and [EmbeddedBarChartBuilder (as you want a bar chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder.html) functions.

The below code it's a translation of your current code, you need to set the data range with `addRange` function, being "B4:C17" cells in this case:

```
function createChart() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var artistsChart = sheet.newChart().asBarChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("B4:C17"))
  .setTitle('Number of Tracks per Artist')
  .setXAxisTitle('Number of  Tracks')
  .setYAxisTitle('Artists')
  .setPosition(4, 7, 0, 0)
  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(artistsChart);
}
```

Notice you should change your function name because the doGet function name is used for [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Method `insertChart(Charts.Chart)` "is not found". Error messages in Google Apps Script can be quite confusing, but once explained, they become a bit easier to follow - what the error really says is that it cannot be called on a `Chart` instance. If you take a look at the docs again, you'll see that it accepts an instance of `EmbeddedChart` and that's what causing the problem.

**Solution**

Instead of constructing the Chart using `Charts` service, use `newChart()` method - it yields an `EmbeddedChartBuilder` instance which you can configure however you like, call `build()` on it and pass the resulting `EmbeddedChart` to `insertChart`.

**References**

1. `newChart()` method [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart)
2. `EmbeddedChartBuilder` class [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)
3. `EmbeddedChart` class [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart)

**Notes**

If I knew that from the start, it would've saved me a lot of debug time - as a general rule of thumb, if you see an error msg with "cannot find method", you are trying to pass in an argument of *diff type / class instance* than required (e.g. passing `undefined`)