# Create EmbeddedChart in Google Sheets without using Range, with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create an EmbeddedChart in Google Sheets without using Range in my spreadsheet, but using my own values that I've calculated. After searching for hours, I'm not finding the solution.
What is the best way to do this ?
(To sump up I want to use the EmbeddedChartBuilder class like the ChartBuilder class)

Comment: Can I ask you about `the EmbeddedChartBuilder class like the ChartBuilder class`?

Comment: The ChartBuilder class has the methods "addRow" and "addColumn". This is exactly what in want to do : build a virtual range to create my chart.
[Find the example here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, is what you want to use this? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts

Comment: I've previously tried to create a Chart in Google Sheets using the "Charts" Class, but I didn't succeed. So I've asked on stack overflow what was wrong in my code and the reply was that I was using the wrong class. [You can find my previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059164/adding-a-chart-in-google-sheets-with-google-script).
So I'm trying to use the "EmbedddeChartBuilder" to do what I want, but this class can only use Range, so data in cells of a spreadsheet. So I'm trying to find the best way to build a chart in Google Sheets, but without using data in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that you might want to use [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts). Here, I have one more question. When you put the chart using Charts Service, you want to control the chart using a mouse? If you want to do it, I think that it is required to put the chart to the dialog on Spreadsheet. If you are not required to do it, the chart is put to the Spreadsheet as the image. How about this?

Comment: I haven't understand what you proposed. I want to create a regular chart [like this](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/insert-charts-graphs-google-sheets) but not using the buttons in Google Sheets, but with Google Script. I think I'm not clear in my explanations, and I'm sorry. Is it clearer now ?
So yes, I want to use the Charts Service, but people told me that I wasn't the right way to create charts. But maybe they were wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When [the Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts) is used and you want to manage the chart, I thought that putting the chart to the dialog on Spreadsheet is suitable for your situation. Because the created chart cannot be directly put to the Spreadsheet. So as a wrapper, the dialog is used. I think that this might be the reason of the issue of your previous question. Here, I would like to confirm your goal, again. You want to create a chart with clickable using Charts Service and put to the Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think yes, that want I want. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could correctly understand about your goal. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? I used [your script in your previous script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059164/adding-a-chart-in-google-sheets-with-google-script) as a test case. If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create a chart with clickable using Charts Service and put to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, I used the script of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60059164/7108653) by modifying a little. In this case, in your script, the values from the column "C2:C" are retrieved and the chart is created using the values and duplicated numbers of the values.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, in order to create the chart with clickable, the chart is created by Google Visualization API and put to a dialog on Spreadsheet.

#### Usage:

In order to run the script, please run the function of `openDialog()` at the script editor after copied and pasted the following scripts. By this, a dialog is opened to the Spreadsheet and the chart is put to the dialog.

In this sample script, the values are retrieved from the column "C" of the sheet of `const sheetName = "Sheet1"` in the Spreadsheet. So please use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### Sample script: `Code.gs` (Google Apps Script side)

```
const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

// Please run this function.
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setWidth(650).setHeight(550);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getRange(`C2:C${sheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues()
    .reduce((o, [e]) => {
      o[e] = e in o ? o[e] + 1 : 1
      return o;
    }, {});
}
```

#### Sample script: `index.html` (HTML&Javascript side)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(artists => {
      var dataArtists = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataArtists.addColumn('string', 'Artists');
      dataArtists.addColumn('number', 'Count');
      for(var key in artists) {
        dataArtists.addRow([key, artists[key]]);
      }
      const options = {
        title: 'Number of Tracks per Artist',
        vAxis: {title: "Artists"},
        hAxis: {title: "Number of  Tracks"},
        width: 600,
        height: 500
      };
      barsVisualization = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      barsVisualization.draw(dataArtists, options);
    }).getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  }
</script>
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the chart created with the modified script of your script is put to the Spreadsheet as an image. In this case, the chart is put by running the function of `myFunction` created with [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts). In this case, the data is retrieved from the active sheet. Please be careful this.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var artistsArray;
  var dataArtists;
  dataArtists = Charts.newDataTable().addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Artists').addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Count');
  var artists = sheet.getRange(`C2:C${sheet.getLastRow()}`).getValues()
    .reduce((o, [e]) => {
      o[e] = e in o ? o[e] + 1 : 1
      return o;
    }, {});
  for(var key in artists) {
    dataArtists.addRow([key, artists[key]]);
  }
  dataArtists.build();
  var artistsChart = Charts.newBarChart()
  .setDataTable(dataArtists)
  .setTitle('Number of Tracks per Artist')
  .setXAxisTitle('Number of  Tracks')
  .setYAxisTitle('Artists')
  .setDimensions(600, 500)
  .build();
  sheet.insertImage(artistsChart.getBlob(), 1, 1);
}
```

### Note:

- In this case, please enable V8 at the script editor.

### References:

- [Using Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs)
- [Google Visualization API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)
- [Bar Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)
- [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts)